# Getting the first URL alias for a node in a SQL query

Tags: 6, database, path-aliases

For some backups and exports, I need to fetch the URL-aliases for each node in SQL. 
The `url_alias` taqble, however, has no foreign key to the node table (nid) nor the other way around, it seems.

Is there some hidden join-table somewhere? A neat trick to fetch the node and its alias in a JOIN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the value in the `src` column in the `url_alias` table is predictable for nodes you can just query it directly, without the need for any joins:

```
$nid = 1; // node id
$src = 'node/' . $nid;
$query = db_query("SELECT dst FROM {url_alias} WHERE src = '%s'", $src);
```

If you definitely want to use a join though, something like this will work:

```
SELECT n.nid, ua.dst
FROM {node} n 
INNER JOIN {url_alias} ua ON ua.src = CONCAT('node/', n.nid)
```

Comment: Thanks, the concat in the ON is exactly what I was looking for. Performs horribly, but not a huge problem here.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7 and there is no such field `ua.src` I needed to change it to this: `INNER JOIN {url_alias} ua ON ua.source = CONCAT('node/', n.nid)`, and now it works.

Comment: How to do this with db_select.